# Creating a 4v4 custom game?

Tags: starcraft-2

I can't find the option to create a 4v4 custom game. How do I do this? The loby opens with a 5v3 setup and I can't move the 5th to the second team.

Edit: Nevermind, suddenly it started to work. I have no idea why. Perhaps some battle.net bug.

Edit2: I'm so stupid... I left the loby and the bug is back now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 5 people in a party and create a custom game this happens.

What you need to do is cancel the party and then start a custom game, select 4v4 mode and add people manually using the Add Player button (Near Add AI button).

Note: not verified, i do not have any friends online now.

I will describe the steps to create a 4v4 custom game:

Select Multi Player at the top left part of the SC2 screen 
Select Create Custom Game on the bottom right part of the SC2 screen
Select a map for 8 players (for example Lava Flow) 
At the right side of the screen, select 4v4 from a drop box
Add players as you like and play

This works fine for me and i have never had any problems.

Comment: I don't have any party. I simply create a new custom game on a 8 player map and the loby starts in a 5v3 setup. And I can't drop a 4th player into a team.

Comment: And there is no way how to change it to a 4v4 setup?

Comment: You can create as many 3 player teams as you want :) But not a 4 player team.

Mele seems to work fine, but that doesn't work with team oriented maps (players are just placed at random and not top-bottom or whatever the map is supposed to be).

Comment: Updated the answer with step-by-step instructions on how to create a 4v4 custom game that works for me well.

Comment: Well, that is melee, but what happens if you select the custom category?

Comment: Dont know about custom, but if you do this because you want those "custom game achievements" then no worries, it counts in "melee", you just need to create a Multiplayer->Custom Game every time. (not a Single Player game)

Comment: The new Battle.net interface is abysmal in terms of functionality.